# How to make an application first get notifed when there is internet connection in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android application. The requirement of this application is that, my app should get notify **first** among all the other installed app (which are using internet permission) on the phone. I know that broadcast reciever can be used to listen for any intent thrown by android os.. How to know that my application will get internet connection notification **first** then other app ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain this behaviour. Your app with broadcast receiver receive parallel system messages as others apps.

Comment: Thanks michal, one more question. can i explicity stop broadcasting of internet connection intent, when there is internet connection ?

Comment: You also can't do it (because system send this intent).

Comment: but, in settings of device, there will be toggle button to turn the net connection on and off rite ? same thing can be achieved through coding also rite ?

Comment: No way, this functionality is unavailable for programmers from security reasons. Imagine that someone open mobile internet access and start download big files when you pay for using bandwidth (no for permanent access).